# Margin of right div should match the left textarea width while resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

When resizing the left `<textarea>` (with the bottom-right-corner resize area), **how to have the right `<div>`'s margin automatically match the `<textarea>`'s width?**

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#a {  width: 50%; resize: horizontal; height: 100%; position: fixed; }
#b { margin-left: 50%; }
```

```html
<textarea id="a">hello</textarea>
<div id="b">h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h</div>
```

Note: the left textarea should always take 100% of the browser height (always displayed editor), whereas the right div can have a very long height (many pages to be scrolled).

---

Edit: this **nearly** works:

```js
$('#a').data('x', $('#a').outerWidth()).mousemove(function () {
        if ($('#a').outerWidth() != $('#a').data('x')) {
            $('#b').css('margin-left', $('#a').outerWidth());
            $('#a').data('x', $('#a').outerWidth());
        }
    });
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#a {  width: 50%; resize: horizontal; height: 100%; position: fixed; }
#b { margin-left: 50%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="a">hello</textarea>
<div id="b">h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h</div>
```

but it doesn't work if you click down on the textareas's resizing area, **and then drag the mouse out of the browser window** (or if you drag the window over the console panel of the browser).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with `position: fixed` - you could put everything in a flex container and set the `textarea` to `height: 100vh`. Try running the snippet below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#flex {
  display: flex;
}
#a {
  width: 50%;
  resize: horizontal;
}
```

```html
<div id='flex'>
  <textarea id="a">hello</textarea>
  <div id="b">h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @DanKreiger, but the left textarea  should always keep 100% of the browser height, and not move when we scroll the page. (see what happens with my code snippet when you scroll the whole page vertically: the left textarea doesn't move) How to modify your code to do that?

Comment: I just noticed that - I'll have a look.

Comment: I just updated the snippet. You can scroll on the right `<div>`, but perhaps you want to scroll on everything?

Comment: This won't work @DanKreiger, because when you'll print the page in the browser, it will print only one page (with the internal scrollbar printed as well :) )

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
var a_width = $("#a").outerWidth();
    $("#a").mouseup(function () {
     if (a_width != $("#a").outerWidth()) {
      a_width = $("#a").outerWidth();
      $("#b").css( { marginLeft : a_width });
     }
    });
```

Comment: Isn't this nearly the same than my snippet at the end of the question (after "Edit"). Can you edit your your answer to use a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/1422096) (it allows us to quickly test it). Thanks in advance.